# Android showing results of the query to the server

Tags: android

I develop app which will download information from Internet server and show search results in ListView. When user clicks on item more detailed information will be shown. 
The question is whether to write search results before showing to DB or not? I know that Activity lifecycle can loose all data and some developers recomend to do it safe, but is it really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense to persist the data because if the activity is destroyed and you lose the data while the user has switched to instant messenger or mailer, the user will have to re-download the data from the server, which causes extra traffic and potentially money loss. 
Also it doesn't necessarily need to be a DB - you can just use some temporary file. But you do need to persist this data.

Comment: @Mighter Depending on how much data you have and how they are formatted bundle can be an option

Comment: That would be ArrayList of custom class instances. Perhaps bundle is not suitable... Yet another question: how do I know whether Activity was started explicitly by my app or re-created after being killed by OS?

Comment: @Mighter There's no such thing as "re-created". It's always started from the beginning, so you can always load previous data. One idea is to store time when your application is off-loaded, and check how much time passed since last launch and act accordingly. For example, if the data is more than one day old, you can ask the user if he wants to refresh it. This would be more useful, then just deciding if the data should be re-loaded.

Comment: I mean that there might be difference if I use startActivity(...) in my code and if Activity was killed to free memory and then started again?

Comment: @Mighter I don't think there can be any difference. If the process is gone, then it's gone. The user starts it as usually after that. In general, the activity is destroyed when the user presses Back button, not just due to running out of memory. And the general rule is not to try invent something custom but base your code on guidelines - if the activity is destroyed, save it's state if you want, and then re-create it on next launch, no matter what initiated destroying and recreation.